# Android print on specific position regardeless of resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this scenario:

- An activity with a global layout that has a background image that fills it up.
- In such image (provided by designer) there is a white box where some text is supposed to be printed with information from the app at runtime.
- We are having problems to understand how we can print in the same position regardless of screen resolution and density... Whenever we change the tablet we get wrong positions for the text...

Any hints?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to ask the designer to break out the box from the image, and then you aren't worried about the exact nuance of image placement.

Okay, so what if that's not an option? This is where you have to go pixel counting. I would recommend you do the following:

1. Devote an entire class to getting the text right. This class should extend [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), or one of it's subclasses.
2. In the class, you can determine the size of the image, but not at `onCreate`. You'll have to determine this in a custom View [`onMeasure`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29).
3. This class will have to figure out how to stretch the image appropriately, and based on how it's stretched, figure out where the text box should go.

Hopefully this is enough to get a start on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am afraid the easiest way will be to break up image. I can as it is layered, but somo texts are "hardcoded" and will have to ask the designer to remove them... I wish this was an already resolved issue under Androd. Regards!

Comment: By the way, I cannot vote you as I have not reached the 15 points yet. Sorry for that ! EDIT: I finally could ! ;-)